# When using Uploadcare how can make sure no one can access the cropped section?

Tags: cdn, uploadcare

We have an upload widget in our web app where users upload photos. Also, a user can crop the photo in the widget. So a URL for a photo looks like this:

```
https://ucarecdn.com/703fd439-34e1-4a6c-8868-3dcc9ea3ddf1/-/crop/273x273/172,143/-/preview/
```

But the user cropped the photo for a reason, and he wouldn't want the cropped sections to be viewed by other users. But anyone can just copy the link and remove the crop suffix like so:

https://ucarecdn.com/703fd439-34e1-4a6c-8868-3dcc9ea3ddf1/

And now he can access the whole photo.
Is there anyway to tell Uploadcare CDN to make the original source hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy file via [REST API](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/rest/#files-post) (most of Uploadcare libs support this).
In your case you want to set `source` to cropped URL, so the new file will have no extra image info. After that you may remove the original upload and use the new URL in your app.